# How does Azure allocate VM with Ubuntu?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have been curious about this, and wanted to know how it works?
Where is the OS running? From where does the OS get memory and CPU to run the OS?

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?  If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Azure VM works like the VM in the Windows Server with the Hyper-V. So you can take a look at the virtualization of Hyper-V [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/). And the Hyper-V also supports the Linux Os even in the Windows Server. All the VMs in the same Windows Server use the resources such as the CPU and the memory of the host server.

Azure is a Public Cloud. It uses the cluster of the Windows Servers to provide the Infrastructure such as the VM. [Here](https://www.vembu.com/blog/azure-iaas-vm-infrastructure-sizes-and-pricing/) you can get more details about it.